# SSL policy errors have been encountered. Error code '0x2'

Tags: 2013, ssl

I have encountered an error on a new install of SharePoint in trying to resolve my Search Service issues.

- APP1
- WFE1/WFE2
- SQL

I am getting the subject error.  I have tried to recreate the cert on both WFEs.  Could someone elaborate more on what's being discussed here:

[Extended sharepoint site (SSL enabled) with https not accessible](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200568/extended-sharepoint-site-ssl-enabled-with-https-not-accessible)

I am confused about the FQDN, am I renaming my actual server from SP13-WFE1 to the FQDN I have for SharePoint?  What about the other servers?  Or am I just renaming the Subject on the cert, if so, how do I add two names as suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I tried everything on Google I could find.

- Added SharePoint Service cert to the trusted store
- Added SharePoint Service certs from all the WFE to CA Manage Trust
- Tried removing SSL warnings via web.config on both WFE

The only thing that worked was changing the servers to their FQDN.  What I realized is FQDN is not https://sharepoint.contoso.com it's...sp13-wfe1.consto.controller.svcs (or something like that).  The NetBIOS name was SP13-WFE1.  When I changed to the FQDN (via PowerShell on each respective server) and rebooted, it worked like a charm.

The command would be something like:

```
Rename-SPServer -Identity "sp13-wfe1" -Name "sp13-wfe1.contoso.controller.svcs"
```

Hopefully this helps!